# GCP cloud composer nodes intermittently enter crashloopbackoff state during the course of day

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

We have been facing a rather strange issue where our pods in one of the GKE managed cloud composer cluster is unhealthy and this has resulted in multiple job failure on the past few weeks.

We are not sure for now, why would such pods enter this state and restart again after few attempts on the same node and work just like normal as if nothing ever happened.

How can this be troubleshooted?

Comment: Did you find anything in the events or in log?

Comment: No, nothing of great information which leads me to indicate why the cluster is not resilient and why the pods are being evicted.

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the cluster logs? Have you noticed if this happens during a specific DAG run?

Comment: No, not really, all throughout the day in an ad-hoc manner. Moreover, this is seen across all deployments and job kinds on cloud composer which runs on GKE.